# ¿Es posible una oración que solo tenga palabras con úes?

Tags: letras, vocales

He podido ver frases, oraciones como *Este es el creyente hereje* (valga la paradoja), o [canciones](https://www.letras.com/leon-gieco/198004/) donde se usa una y solo una vocal. Sin embargo no he podido ver ejemplos ni se me ocurren con la letra 'u'. Algo como *Tu usas tutú* falla por la 'a' de "usas", y en general creo que cualquier oración propia fallará por falta de verbos con la letra 'u', pero quisiera que me confirmaran si de veras no existe ejemplo alguno o si, aunque escondida, la letra 'u' tiene su oración propia.

Comment: Con verbo es imposible, ya que no existe ningún verbo moderno que solo contenga U.   Los vanguardistas tenían muchos poemas que empleaban apenas una vocal, pero las con U no contenían oraciones formalmente completas por dicha falta

Comment: No hay oraciones, pero aquí hay un lindo ejemplo de lo que se puede hacer usando solo con el sonido de la *u* como vocal https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TiO0jlDQrrg

Comment: En efecto, es una pena, pero no se puede. Simplemente comentar que me extraña que nadie haya enlazado aún esta canción del rapero Nach, que hace una con solo A, otra con solo E y otra con solo O: https://genius.com/Nach-efectos-vocales-lyrics (ver los "versos"). Después, Berto Romero hizo en el famoso programa de Buenafuente uno con la letra i, curioso cuando menos. No pudieron hacer nada con la u.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No existen formas verbales que no tengan en su terminación alguna de las otras cuatro vocales, de modo que sólo se podría construir oraciones incompletas, o en el estrecho campo de las oraciones de [verbo omitido](https://blog.lengua-e.com/2013/coma-cuando-se-omite-el-verbo/).

**Pero existe una opción**, si aceptamos una pequeña concesión literaria que los mismos literatos aceptan en su contexto.

En el ámbito de la poesía: concretamente en las coplas y [versos de cabo roto](http://lenguaurelio.blogspot.cl/2011/02/versos-de-cabo-roto.html) (gracias walen por señalar el nombre). Incluso se podría concebir una canción, aunque elemental.

Los versos de cabo roto, aunque en su origen le anteceden, fueron muy popularizados por Cervantes. Eran algo más comunes en el Siglo de Oro que en nuestros días, y [apocopan](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%B3cope) sistemáticamente las sílabas que vienen después de la última acentuada del verso. Un ejemplo muy conocido es (paradójicamente) el satírico *laudo* de Urganda la Desconocida, parte de los que incluye Cervantes como prólogo al Quijote:

[image: comienzo del Laudo de Urganda la Desconocida]

Si se deja el verbo para el final del verso, una desinencia de persona y tiempo verbal podría apocoparse: bastaría sólo una raíz con *úes*: turbar, usurpar, usufructuar, etc.

Un ejemplo que trata de construir oraciones coherentes podría ser el siguiente (perdónenme la métrica, que eso ya sería mucho pedir):

> Tu gurú su pudú sutu-;
>
> Luz, tu tutú un frufrú ulu-;
>
> Lulú su cuscús usufructú-

En el primer verso, una eminencia de la medicina veterinaria, gurú del lector, sutura a su pudú mascota. En el segundo, el tutú de una bailarina llamada Luz emite un ruido muy fuerte (grita) producto de la fricción. Mientras tanto Lulú (que puede ser nombre de mujer o un tipo de perro) aprovecha (comiendo) el cuscús que le habían preparado.

Sigue siendo muy poca cosa lo que se puede hacer, y por supuesto, la absoluta ausencia de preposiciones, inexistencia práctica de adverbios y otras párticulas, y el ínfimo vocabulario disponible, (limitado a [poco más de cien palabras, siendo generosos](https://www.solosequenosenada.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/palabras_solo_con_la_vocal_u_2010.txt)) para el resto de la oración no deja hacer mucho.

Me imagino que no es exactamente lo que buscabas con la pregunta, pero logra un poquito más que excluyendo totalmente el verbo y sigue siendo castellano literariamente válido.

### Actualización

Respecto a las oraciones con verbo omitido, la idea es que la acción debe ser evidente por el contexto, o por referencia a la de una oración anterior, por ejemplo:

> *[Tú comerás zanahorias, ¿y yo?]* —Tú, un [chucrut](http://dle.rae.es/?id=92FhFc0).

Tal como señala Rodrigo, es muy frecuente omitir el verbo ser. Probablemente sea el que más se omite. Y eso quizá se deba a la estrechez única entre sujeto y predicado que da la oración copulativa (con verbo ser).

Comment: @walen, ¿Qué les faltaría? Una sílaba. Pero tienen sujeto, verbo y predicado. En ese sentido digo que no es exactamente lo que se pedía, pero llega más cerca

Comment: @Rafael, estoy a punto de darte la respuesta... pero la primera opción que diste (oraciones de verbo omitido), te ayudaría un ejemplo

Comment: @VeAqui, qué tal ahí?

Answer (score 6):

No.

Una oración necesita un verbo, y en español no hay verbos que solo contengan la letra U.
Frases sí: se me ocurre *«Tú, tu tutú, tu puf: un bluf»*, por poner un ejemplo algo bobo. Pero oraciones no.

---

**NOTA**.- Viendo que varios usuarios están poniendo ejemplos con verbo elidido, aclarar que mi ejemplo también elide el verbo *ser*: *«Tú, tu tutú (y) tu puf (sois) un bluf»*.
Describe un escenario en el que una persona intenta hacerse la *sexy* con ropa sugerente ([tutú](http://dle.rae.es/?w=tut%C3%BA)) y mobiliario cómodo ([puf](http://dle.rae.es/?w=puf)), pero la otra le echa en cara que solo es un farol ([bluf](http://dle.rae.es/?w=bluf)).
Ya dije que era un ejemplo bobo :D
Sin embargo, bobo o no, no lo considero una oración.

Answer (score 3):

Mi granito de arena: una oración copulativa con verbo elidido (una estructura gramatical bastante frecuente), en este caso comprensible por su sentido religioso:

> *Su cruz: tu luz.*